# Column chart highlight/glow color/opacity

Tags: google-visualization, column-chart

I've been making Google charts of some data and so far everything is good, except for one thing - highlight of columns is not dark enough, even though color is #000, opacity of rectangles that create the glow are 0.3, 0.15, 0.05.
The glow in question:
[image]

I've scoured internet and failed to find some convenient way of doing this. So I came up with this rather 'barbaric' way:

```
function draw(e)
{
    $('[stroke-opacity="0.3"]').attr('stroke-opacity',0.7);
    $('[stroke-opacity="0.15"]').attr('stroke-opacity',0.55);
    $('[stroke-opacity="0.05"]').attr('stroke-opacity',0.45);
}
```

which while does what I need, doesn't seem to be the most efficient way of doing this. So the question is, is there any better/more efficient of changing opacity of rectangles that form glow around columns?
P.S. There can be up to 3 column charts on the same page if that matters.

Comment: you can use a [`style` column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) to set `stroke-opacity` -- [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35709373/5090771) is an example of adding a style column using a DataView

Comment: @WhiteHat I think it targets `stroke-opacity` of bar itself, not its glow